# Angular 2 Binding in HTML to Specific Length

Tags: html, angular

I am creating a list of movies with:

```
<li *ngFor="let movie of movies">
   <span class="badge">{{movie.title}}</span>
   {{movie.year}}
</li>
```

It looks good for some movies, but bad for others. How can I ensure that movie.title will always display 15 characters? Some movies will be less than that I want to add padding to the end and some will be more that I want to trim and add '...' to the end.

Example:

```
Game of Thrones
Not Game of ...
Some Other M...
```

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: text-overflow: ellipsis

Comment: you need implement the custom pipe

Comment: Make use of pipes

Comment: I agree with @Vega. It's a good idea to do it via css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the width of the `span` and you can do this:

```
.badge{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: calc(100% - 0.5rem) ;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The li width could be calculated with 'rem's and depending on the space you intend to allocate to it.

This is an approximate styling, it need to be adjusted on your example.

Comment: Thank you. I think styling with CSS opposed to the Angular Pipes is better for this situation.

Comment: Neat solution +1